# problem of Firmware commands in ros_arduino_bridge package

Tags: ros, ros-arduino-bridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I git clone the ros_arduino_bridge package, and modified it according to README file and my hardware equipment. And when I test the firmware commands with my arduino mega 2560, it outputs nothing whatever I enter any command, but the LED of RX blinks. I'm very very confused, who can help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235335/problem-of-firmware-commands-in-ros_arduino_bridge-package/) by [Fighting_bird](https://answers.ros.org/users/26255/fighting_bird/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2016-05-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The baud rate set in the Serial Monitor of the Arduino IDE needs to match the baud rate set in the ROSArduinoBridge firmware which is 57600 by default.  This is actually explained in the [documentation](https://github.com/hbrobotics/ros_arduino_bridge) which I quote below:

> **NOTE**: Before trying these commands,
> set the Serial Monitor baudrate to
> 57600 and the line terminator to
> "Carriage return" or "Both NL & CR"
> using the two pulldown menus on the
> lower right of the Serial Monitor
> window.

**EDIT**: Please confirm the following three steps:

(1) In the ROSArduinoBridge.ino file, make sure you have the following #define:

```
#define BAUDRATE     57600
```

(2) Compile and upload the sketch to your Arduino.

(3) In the Arduino IDE, open the Serial Monitor and set its baud rate to 57600 and the line ending to Carriage Return.

Then try the firmware commands.

Also, you do not specify the hardware you are using to run ROS.  Are you using a serial port that is capable of baud rates greater than 9600?

---

Originally posted by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) with karma: 4046 on 2016-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Fighting_bird](https://answers.ros.org/users/26255/fighting_bird/) on 2016-05-27**:
Thank you for your help very much. I understand what you mean, but as what I said in my question--it output nothing if I set baud rate to 57600. But when I set it ro 9600, it just works fine. So I don't know why and I am very eager for your explanation.

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2016-05-27**:
Please see the Edit to my answer above.

**Comment by [Fighting_bird](https://answers.ros.org/users/26255/fighting_bird/) on 2016-05-28**:
Thank you for your answer very much. I followed your step, but it output nothing. And I debug the program by making it output what it has read to serial monitor, and I get some gibberish characters. BTY, I run ROS  on my laptop computer, and I think the baud rate of its serial port can get to 57600.

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2016-05-28**:
That is very strange.  Can you try using a different sketch on your Arduino such as the Example/AnalogReadSerial sketch and see if you get the same problem.  I can reproduce your results with the AnalogReadSerial sketch if I make the sketch baud rate different than the Serial Monitor baud rate.